# Is it possible to use Selenium in python to get the curl of a media file in chrome?

Tags: selenium, curl, selenium-chromedriver, inspect-element

[image]

In Chrome inspector, there is the functionality to get the cURL of a media file. Is it possible to automate the same operation in Selenium by using python? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find the URL of the image by finding the image element with `find_element*` and then get the "href" attribute with `get_attribute`

cookies can be retrieved via `driver.get_cookies()`

I think the headers you would have to construct yourself

and at the end you would have to put it all together in a cURL request